# Pod CPU / Memory requests in error state are not released

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have some pods created by CronJobs that are in `Error` state and it seems that the CPU / Memory requested by these pods are not released since kubelet is not killing them. It prevents other pods from being scheduled.

Is that the expected behavior ? Should I clean them by hand to get the resources back ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if the pods were scheduled to the node and an error occurred after that, you need to delete those pods to cleanup resources.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @KamolHasan. What about pods in `Completed` state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pods in `Error` you should delete this pod to release resources assigned to it.

However pods in `Completed` or `Failed` status are not required to be cleaned up to release resources allocated to them. It can be checked by running simple `Job` to check memory resources allocated in node.

Memory allocation before job:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        811m (86%)   1143m (121%)
  memory                     555Mi (19%)  1115Mi (39%)
```

Job example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: test-job
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - date
        image: busybox
        name: test-job
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 200Mi
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Memory after the job deployment:

```
  Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        811m (86%)   1143m (121%)
  memory                     555Mi (19%)  1115Mi (39%)
```